# "TypeError: string indices must be integers" after reading from a JSON file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to duplicate a simple code in my reading material where I want to extract data from a JSON file and plot dots at the capitals of countries on a map.

Regarding my issue,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\serta\Desktop\python\db\capitals.py", line 14, in <module>
    lons.append(cp_dicts['geometries']['coordinates'][0])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
[Finished in 188ms]
```

I read similar posts here and I think I understand the "why" of the issue,I double checked my []'s and the depths of the nests but I cannot seem to fix it myself.

I am pretty sure I am looking at an integer where I target with my code (lons.append line) but I am still getting the "TypeError: string indices must be integers".

Here is the code:

```
import json

from plotly.graph_objs import Scattergeo, Layout
from plotly import offline

#Explore the structure of the data.
filename = 'data/capitals.topo.json'
with open (filename) as f:
    all_cp_data = json.load(f)

all_cp_dicts=all_cp_data
lons,lats,hover_texts =[],[],[]
for cp_dicts in all_cp_dicts['objects']['capitals']:
    lons.append(cp_dicts['geometries']['coordinates'][0])
    lats.append(cp_dicts['geometries']['coordinates'][1])
    hover_texts.append(cp_dicts['properties']['capital'])

#Map the earthquakes.
data = [{
    'type':'scattergeo',
    'lon':lons,
    'lat':lats,
    'text': hover_texts,
    'marker':{
        'size': [5],
        #'color': mags,
        #'colorscale': 'plasma',
        #'reversescale':True,
        #'colorbar':{'title':'Magnitude'},
    },
}]
my_layout = Layout(title="Capital Cities")

fig ={'data':data, 'layout':my_layout}
offline.plot(fig, filename ='capital_cities.html')
```

Here is also the capitals.topo.json I am using:

```
{
  "type": "Topology",
  "objects": {
    "capitals": {
      "type": "GeometryCollection",
      "geometries": [
        {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            90.24,
            23.43
          ],
          "id": "BD",
          "properties": {
            "country": "Bangladesh",
            "city": "Dhaka",
            "tld": "bd",
            "iso3": "BGD",
            "iso2": "BD"
          }
        },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 14, this is not valid, given the input data:
`lons.append(cp_dicts['geometries']['coordinates'][0]`

You need to update the loop along these lines:

```
for geometry in all_cp_dicts['objects']['capitals']['geometries']:

    lons.append(geometry['coordinates'][0])
    lats.append(geometry['coordinates'][1])
    hover_texts.append(geometry['properties'].get('city', ""))
```

Note that for some of the locations, the 'cities' key is missing in the json.  So you need to handle that when populating the `hover_texts` list, as shown.

Also, the 'data' variable was not working with Scattergeo.  Below is a suggested revision to the syntax

```
data = Scattergeo(
    lat = lats,
    lon = lons,
    text = hover_texts,
    marker = dict(
        size = 5
        )
    )
```

Comment: Hello Ekrall, thank you for your response. I tried changing the code with the list position, however I am still getting the same error:


`all_cp_dicts=all_cp_data
lons,lats,hover_texts =[],[],[]
for cp_dicts in all_cp_dicts['objects']['capitals']:
 lons.append(cp_dicts['geometries'][0]['coordinates'][0])
 lats.append(cp_dicts['geometries'][0]['coordinates'][1])
 hover_texts.append(cp_dicts['properties']['capital'])
`

Comment: can you post your entire JSON instead of just the snippet?

Comment: I tried to copy paste but it is too long, so here is the link to the file itself:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/azlkiniue/9105f368839fe1ac8ef61adccd62aa81/raw/8efe9d353013db21bdadd815a061795c0fce5abd/capitals.topo.json

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: I see, I made the wrong assumption about how the json was laid out.  See the edited answer above.  Your `data` variable also needs to have its syntax updated.

Comment: Ekrall, the edited answer & corrected syntax for the data worked. Thank you very much for this clarification.